# Is it possible play multiple clips using presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated?

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayer

I have a situation where I'd like to play 2 video clips back to back using an MPMoviePlayerViewController displayed using presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated.

The problem is that the modal view automatically closes itself as soon as the first movie is complete.

Has anyone found a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Three options:

You may use `MPMoviePlayerController` and start the playback of the 2nd (Nth) item after the previous is complete. This however will introduce a small gap between the videos cause by identification and pre buffering of the content.

You may use `AVQueuePlayer`; AVQueuePlayer is a subclass of AVPlayer you use to play a number of items in sequence. See its [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more.

You may use `AVComposition` for at runtime composing one video out of the two (or N) you need to play back. Note, this works only on locally stored videos and not on remote (streaming or progressive download). Then use `AVPlayer` for the playback.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. If the video assets are in local file system, consider AVComposition.